# Distribute costs by day between a given StartDate and EndDate using BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery, date-range, unnest

My table shows the total budget of marketing campaigns for a given period:

| Campaign Name | StartDate | EndDate | Budget (total) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Campaign-1 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-04 | 100 € |
| Campaign-2 | 2023-01-15 | 2023-01-21 | 210 € |

I would like to distribute the total budget per campaign linearly over the days.

Therefore, the result should look like this:

| Campaign Name | Date | Budget (daily) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Campaign-1 | 2023-01-01 | 25 € |
| Campaign-1 | 2023-01-02 | 25 € |
| Campaign-1 | 2023-01-03 | 25 € |
| Campaign-1 | 2023-01-04 | 25 € |
| Campaign-2 | 2023-01-15 | 30 € |
| Campaign-2 | 2023-01-16 | 30 € |
| Campaign-2 | 2023-01-17 | 30 € |
| Campaign-2 | 2023-01-18 | 30 € |
| Campaign-2 | 2023-01-19 | 30 € |
| Campaign-2 | 2023-01-20 | 30 € |
| Campaign-2 | 2023-01-21 | 30 € |

I've come across GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY. However, splitting the budget out to a single date per row has been the hard part.

```
SELECT period
FROM (SELECT MIN(CAST(StartDate AS DATE)) as min_date,
             MAX(CAST(EndDate)) as max_date
      FROM total_budget
     ) tb JOIN
     UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(tb.min_date, tb.max_date)) period
```

Would be glad about help!

Answer (score 2):

You may consider below approach.

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT 'Campaign-1' campaign_name, DATE '2023-01-01' start_date, DATE'2023-01-04' end_date, 100 budget_total UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Campaign-2' campaign_name, '2023-01-15', '2023-01-21', 210
)
SELECT campaign_name, date, budget_total / (DATE_DIFF(end_date, start_date, DAY) + 1) AS budget_daily
  FROM sample_table, UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(start_date, end_date)) date;
```

**Query results**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. It can be so easy when you have it down ;)

Answer (score 0):

Consider also below approach

```
select campaign_name, date, 
  budget_total / count(*) over(partition by campaign_name) as budget_daily
from your_table, unnest(generate_date_array(start_date, end_date)) date
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]