# Split rows in a table based on date fields SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table on BigQuery of invoices containing some payments covering multiple months of the year. The aim is to split theses records in order calculate my monthly revenue.

Here's an example :

For an invoice (1 record) of 5000 USD covering a period starting from the 1st of January 2022 until the 1st of October 2022 (10 months) I want to get 10 rows of 500 USD.

Table :
[image]

Expected output :
[image]

Comment: looks almost same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75019770/distribute-costs-by-day-between-a-given-startdate-and-enddate-using-bigquery-sql   except that the interval is a month rather than a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select id_invoice, amount / count(*) over(partition by id_invoice) amount, min(day) start, max(day) `end`
from your_table t, unnest(generate_date_array(start, `end`)) day
group by id_invoice, t.amount, date_trunc(day, month)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: I appreciate a lot your help Mikhail, your approach worked perfectly !

Answer (score 1):

You might consider below as well.

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT 123 id_invoice, 5000 amount, DATE '2022-01-01' start, DATE '2022-10-31' `end`
)
SELECT id_invoice,
       amount / (DATE_DIFF(`end`, start, MONTH) + 1) AS amount,
       start_of_month AS start,
       LAST_DAY(start_of_month) AS `end`
  FROM sample_table, UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(start, `end`, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) start_of_month;
```